# Using baseadapter to fill in listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

I'm trying to use base adapter to populate my list view with fields from my object (NewsFeedObj)  I'm currently just trying to get the description field. When i run my code i just get a blank activity? Can anyone help me

```
public class News_Feed_BaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private List<NewsFeedObj> obj = Collections.emptyList();

    public News_Feed_BaseAdapter(Context context, List<NewsFeedObj> obj) {
        this.context = context;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return obj.size();
    }

    @Override
    public NewsFeedObj getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return obj.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Description);

        NewsFeedObj o = getItem(position);
        t.setText(o.get_description());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

In the Main activity

```
ArrayList<NewsFeedObj> NewsObjs = new ArrayList<NewsFeedObj>();
NewsObjs = j.new_feed_Array_List(); // returns an array list of
                                    // NewsFeedObj

ListView l = getListView();
News_Feed_BaseAdapter A = new News_Feed_BaseAdapter(this, NewsObjs);

l.setAdapter(A);
```

Comment: Have your tried debugging? That will be easier to figure out what's wrong. Probably your NewsObjs is empty(size 0)

Comment: Hard to say with the code you show. It looks all good to me. Are you sure the ListView itself shows on the screen and you have items in your list? Maybe you could show some more code or your main layout. And just a a note: use the default java/android coding style. It makes your code easier to read for other. Use camelcase and check how variables and methods are named here: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: Are you getting the value of o?

Comment: i tried Log.d("response ok",   "Value of " + t.getText().toString()); to print the value of the description but it is not printing anything

Comment: it seems like the getView() method isn't running

Answer (score 0):

Try calling A.notifyDataSetChanged(); after l.setAdapter(A);

This lets your adapter know that the data it holds a reference to has changed and it needs to update its display of the data.  NewsObjs will need to be a non-empty list, of course.

Comment: I don't think calling notifyDataSetChanged after setAdapter is going to have an affect.

Answer (score 0):

This is also the same issue what you faced in arrayadapter.. I also experienced that.. You just need to do is change the line

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout, parent, false);
```

as

```
convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.newfeed_layout, null);
```

for both ArrayAdapter and BaseAdapter. I'm sure this will work..

Answer (score 0):

j.new_feed_Array_List(); what does this mean..can you elaborate the code.
try this adapter class if it works

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;

}
```

in get view

```
ViewHolder holder;
holder.t=(textView)....
holder.t.setText(...);
```